# Executing PHP in webserver "environment" without Apache (or other webserver)

Tags: php, cgi

Is it possible to execute PHP code from a program that does not interface with the script through a webserver? Initially, I thought of the CLI PHP interpreter, but that doesn't contain any of the $_SERVER or $_REQUEST varaibles common to website requests.

So, if it's possible to emulate, how could the be accumplised? I am not thinking in any specific programming language as i'm sure there is some common interface between webservers and php which would be platform independent.

The aim of this question is to build a Node.JS application that can opperate as a webserver, then (when needed) can execute PHP scripts (with specific inputs), fetch the response, then if needed some additional processing on the output, then write it to the client.

Answer (score 3):

Unless you want to build a PHP module for Node.JS, I think CLI is your only choice - you could pass the required variables through the command line, and I guess nothing speaks against rebuilding them inside the script:

```
php -f myscript.php /websites/myscript domain.com 1.2.3.4.5
```

Now, the *ideal* way would be to take these arguments and write them into variables that you then use in your script.

If you have an existing script that utilizes `$_SERVER`, and don't want to go through rewriting it, this would be a working yet inelegant workaround. (Inelegant because you're not normally supposed to write into `$_SERVER`, `$_GET` and the like.)

```
$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"] = $argv[1];
$_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"] = $argv[2];
$_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"] = $argv[3];
```

[CLI: Command line usage](http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.usage.php)

(I'm not *quite* sure whether overwriting server variables like this is kosher, it feels a bit wrong. But it definitely works in a standard setup. I'll ask the guys in PHP chat what they think... edit: nobody really *likes* it, but there don't seem to be any major downsides)

Comment: I was thinking if I used the CLI method, I would have to serialize the data and parse via arguments, that or use something like memcache. But I did think I would have to build a module, but if there is a good CGI node module available, I would use that (or code my own if it seemed easier)

Comment: @cgoddard yeah. Maybe someone comes up with a module-based solution, that *would* be the nicest way.. although I guess nothing speaks against a memcache here

Comment: Well you don't need the entire data list, just what you want. Is CGI how webservers (like Apache) interface with PHP?

Comment: @cgoddard there is a CGI version and a native Apache module, the latter being much better for performance of course. My  knowledge about how *exactly* they exchange data internally is murky though